# Property 'isExpired' not found on object of type FBSDKAccessToken

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am having an issue while running react native project on IOS. I stumbled upon these two issues.

Showing Recent Issues
/Users/saumyadixit/Documents/Algoworks_Projects/Cheehoo/cheehoo-frontend/cheehoo/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/TokenCaching/FBSDKAccessTokenExpirer.m:52:41: Property 'isExpired' not found on object of type 'FBSDKAccessToken *'

Showing Recent Issues
/Users/saumyadixit/Documents/Algoworks_Projects/Cheehoo/cheehoo-frontend/cheehoo/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/TokenCaching/FBSDKAccessTokenExpirer.m:64:12: Use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKAccessTokenDidExpire'

I am using 4.29.0 version of FBSDK. I tried to update it on 4.38.0 but unable to do so.
I also tried to clear derived data and pod install.

Answer (score 0):

did you try updating facebook sdk?